# Exception after adding await/async code to main.xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have this exception:
[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Messaging.RegistrationAuthorizationException] = {Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Messaging.RegistrationAuthorizationException: HTTP request failed.

```
HTTP Details:
Status: 401
Reason: Unauthorized
Full content: 401ExpiredToken: . TrackingId:8a536a39-5852-4b36-8eae-b7e46ccdfe78_G0,T...
```

I have a Windows Phone 8.1 silverlight application. The application registers itself for toast notifications. All was working fine until I got the request to allow the customer (limited audience) to update the text displayed on the screen. So I provided them with a web form that they can update the content and the phone app reads the content from the web and displays it. 
However after adding this code that uses async/await keywords I now get this new exception when I try to register the notification.

The line that throws is:

```
await hub.RegisterNativeAsync(args.ChannelUri.ToString());
```

I can't see how adding code to main.xaml.cs could impact code in the app.xaml.cs, but it has. My thinking is the await/async keywords are getting confused. Anyone have any idea what might be happening here? BTW:I updated the time in the emulator as that seemed to be the only other time people got this error.

Comment: It turns out I did a sync of the time but not the date on the emulator. The app runs fine now.